# What exactly does 硬 mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

红孩儿 thinks 唐僧 tastes nice. He wants to eat him, but 孙悟空 is onto him. Leaving aside the important question of how he knows 唐僧的味道好, what does this 硬 mean?

看来，硬捉是不行的，不如换个方法！

I'd like to translate: 硬捉 directly grab him, just grab him，but I don't find these meanings for 硬。

硬：hard, strong, tough, firm, obstinate.

Is there another Chinese word which could replace 硬 here?

Answer (score 6):

硬 here connotes *forcefully, without any tactics and etc.*

硬捉 means *to capture/seize/catch merely by force, without any tactics.*

So,

> 看来，硬捉是不行的，不如换个方法！
>
> Looks like, the way of capturing forcefully (without any tactics) wouldn't work, so we might as well change/turn to another way.

The synonym of 硬 in this context can be 强.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, 软 mean **soft** and 硬 means **hard**, also there are other extended meanings, like the idiom, 吃软不吃硬 literally meaning: prefer eating soft (tender method/attitude) rather than hard (tough method/attitude), meaning: (one could only) succumb to tender attitude but not tough attitude. 硬捉是不行的: It is infeasible to catch him toughly, or, It is infeasible to catch him directly.

Answer (score 1):

硬 in here means hard way , so 硬捉 means hard way to catch